# How to connect to remote SQL Server through a vpn using python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I currently have access to a SQL Server by connecting to the company VPN, then use "Remote Desktop Connection" to access a windows system where I can I then can use SSMS to access the company Server to use the specific database that I'm getting data from. I am trying to write a python code that will only make `SELECT` calls to an SQL Server that can only be accessed when using the company's VPN for automating reports.

From my current understanding:

1. I need the `pymssql` library to do this remotely
2. I need to make sure TPC/IP is enabled in "SQL Server Configuration Manager" under `SQL Server Network Configuration`->`Protocols for MSSQLSERVER`
3. Right-click on TPC/IP and click properties to get the IP address and port numbers that can be used to access the database
4. Check the Windows Firewall in Control Center to check if those port numbers are open
5. Then code

I have done all this and check the port number by doing `netstat -ab` in Command Prompt

```
 TCP    999.999.999.999:1234           ServerName:0            LISTENING
 [sqlservr.exe]
```

From my understanding this should be all I need to do since I use "Windows Authentication" to access the server.

```py
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='ServerName', 
                       database='DBname',
                       port=1234)
```

If I run the code above I get

```
OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ServerName:1234)\n')
```

I'm not sure if I'm making the TCP call at all or if I'm failing the "Windows Authentication". I'm not sure if I need to use my username and password for the VPN as well. Does anyone know how I need to get this connection to work?

Excess info if needed: I'm coding in python 3.7 and Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio 2014

Comment: Have you installed FreeTDS ?? http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/freetds.html

Comment: on my machine or the remote desktop? No on my machine. I don't know if its on the remote desktop

Comment: In client machine

Comment: OpenSSL is installed now. still doesn't work

Comment: "I need the pymssql library to do this" - Not necessarily. In fact, if you are trying to do this from a Windows machine you'd probably have an easier time using pyodbc and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

Comment: I'm doing this on windows, but I'm trying to make the code something that can be used on any company computer (mac and windows) that is connected to the company VPN and has permissions to access the SQL server.

Comment: I pulled up the ODBC Data Source Administrator and I have ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server. Will that work or do I need to download the 2017 version?